# Opengl es high resolution iphone 4

Tags: opengl-es

I created an empty iOS project and then added a custom GLView class which is then added to AppDelegate. I have following questions:

1) How do I enable hi-res retina mode on iPhone 4? Currently I am using the following code to check for device:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    NSLog(@"iPad detected");
}
else {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2) {
        NSLog(@"iPhone4 detected");
        _view.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"iPhone detected");
    }
}

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//self.window.rootViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.window addSubview:_view];
```

But even after setting content factor it is drawing pretty poor quality polygons with jagged edges as shown in the image below:

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7358/8725549609_e2ed1e0e2a_b.jpg

Is there any way to set the resolution to 960x640 instead of the default 480x320 ?

Please note that I can not use "someImage@2x.png" because I am generating images at runtime in the render buffer.

2) Second problem I am having is this warning message:

```
"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question I do not know the pipeline of GLView initializer but content scale must be set before the render buffer is made (usually before `renderbufferStorage::` method). To see if dimensions of the buffer are correct (should be 960x640) use function:

```
GLint width;
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &width)
```

Even if the buffer is retina and dimensions are correct those polygons might still be jagged if you do not use any sort of anti-alias. The easiest way to make an antialiased GL view in iOS is probably multisampling, try searching for `glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE()` (you will need a few more lines beside this one though).